# Column 23: document type does not allow element "LINK" here

Tags: html, html4

this is the page - http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/contact.php

Column 23: document type does not allow element "LINK" here

The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).

One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).

i dont no what to do...?

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand what you are trying to achieve here. Can you please try to explain in a little more detail what you want to do? (Do you want a clickable link, or do you want to define a relationship to another document, as the `<link>` tag was created for?)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3), the `<link>` element is only allowed inside the `<head>` element in your document. Perhaps you mean to use `<a>` element here?

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="link1" 
                onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">
        <em><img src="images/formB.jpg" alt="שליחה"></em>
    </a>
    <link href="tenks.php">
</div>
```

Perhaps needs to be

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="link1" 
                onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">
        <em><img src="images/formB.jpg" alt="שליחה"></em>
    </a>
    <a href="tenks.php">tenks</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your intention with that element? if you don't want to see it, why is it there?

Comment: As you can see - there's a picture that is at the end of 'send'
And in fact what we put now is the same thing only appears as a link or picture + link

http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/mix_mastering06.php

Will refresh the page to see the change ...